# Не работает switch

Tags: javascript

Решая школьную задачку столкнулся с тем что не понимаю почему следующая конструкция switch не работает, подскажите почему?

```
var age = 18 
switch(age){
        case (age >= 18 && age <= 59):
            console.log("Вам работать и работать ");
            break;
        case (age > 59):
            console.log("Вам пора на пенсию");
            break;
        case (age >= 1 &&  age <= 17):
            console.log("Вам рано работать");
            break;
    }
```

Comment: В case ожидаются значения, с которыми сравнивается переменная из switch(), а у вас выражения... Не в каждом языке еще допускается их помещать в case-конструкцию, но даже если допускается, то они возвращают булевые значения, а не число... В общем и не должно работать.

Comment: т.е, что бы пример заработал нужно писать, что то типа                   case 18:                                                                                                  case 19:                                                                                ....console.log("Вам работать и работать ");                                                             или просто всё переписать через if

Comment: Ага. Вам обязательно через switch задачу нужно решить или допускается другое решение?

Comment: да мне то просто интересны варианты написания )))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

При работе `switch` параметр сравнивается со значением меток.
Конкретно в данном случае: параметр число, значением меток - true или false

если заменить `switch(age)` на `switch(true)` все заработает.

```js
var age = 18
switch (true) {
  case (age >= 18 && age <= 59):
    document.write("Вам работать и работать ");
    break;
  case (age > 59):
    document.write("Вам пора на пенсию");
    break;
  case (age >= 1 && age <= 17):
    document.write("Вам рано работать");
    break;
}
```

Comment: Да вы гений, черт возьми!)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, что есть, то есть :-D

Comment: Вы удивитесь, но [в Go `switch` без выражения так и делает](https://tour.golang.org/flowcontrol/11)... :)

Comment: @D-side, там так и написано - тоже самое что и switch(true)